# odd scala compile do not failed but give the wrong answer

Tags: scala, compiler-errors

I have following scala code. I make a mistaken by put the CLASS_TYPE following the MAX_DATA_PAGE_SIZE define. I thought this can not be compiled, or it can give the right answer, but it output 0, why this happened?

```
object hello extends App{
    val baseSize = 256
    val MIN_DATA_PAGE_SIZE = math.max(baseSize, 1024)
    val MAX_DATA_PAGE_SIZE =  MIN_DATA_PAGE_SIZE * scala.math.pow(2, CLASS_TYPE-1).toInt
    val CLASS_TYPE: Int = 2

    println(MAX_DATA_PAGE_SIZE)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, this wouldn't compile in a language like C++ because of the uninitialised variable usage. As Dmitry's answer mentions the compiler does warn you though. However the scala is compiles down to Java like this:

```
~$ scalac -print hello.scala

hello.scala:4: warning: Reference to uninitialized value CLASS_TYPE
    val MAX_DATA_PAGE_SIZE =  MIN_DATA_PAGE_SIZE * scala.math.pow(2, CLASS_TYPE-1).toInt
                                                                     ^
[[syntax trees at end of                   cleanup]] // hello.scala
package <empty> {
  object hello extends Object with App {
    <stable> <accessor> def executionStart(): Long = hello.this.executionStart;
    @deprecatedOverriding("executionStart should not be overridden", "2.11.0") private[this] val executionStart: Long = _;
    final <accessor> def _args(): Array[String] = hello.this._args;
    private[this] var _args: Array[String] = _;
    final <accessor> def _args_=(x$1: Array[String]): Unit = {
      hello.this._args = x$1;
      ()
    };
    final <stable> <accessor> def initCode(): scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer = hello.this.initCode;
    private[this] val initCode: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer = _;
    <accessor> def scala$App$_setter_$executionStart_=(x$1: Long): Unit = {
      hello.this.executionStart = x$1;
      ()
    };
    <accessor> def initCode_=(x$1: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer): Unit = {
      hello.this.initCode = x$1;
      ()
    };
    @deprecatedOverriding("args should not be overridden", "2.11.0") def args(): Array[String] = scala.App$class.args(hello.this);
    @deprecated("The delayedInit mechanism will disappear.", "2.11.0") override def delayedInit(body: Function0): Unit = scala.App$class.delayedInit(hello.this, body);
    @deprecatedOverriding("main should not be overridden", "2.11.0") def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = scala.App$class.main(hello.this, args);
    private[this] val baseSize: Int = _;
    <stable> <accessor> def baseSize(): Int = hello.this.baseSize;
    private[this] val MIN_DATA_PAGE_SIZE: Int = _;
    <stable> <accessor> def MIN_DATA_PAGE_SIZE(): Int = hello.this.MIN_DATA_PAGE_SIZE;
    private[this] val MAX_DATA_PAGE_SIZE: Int = _;
    <stable> <accessor> def MAX_DATA_PAGE_SIZE(): Int = hello.this.MAX_DATA_PAGE_SIZE;
    private[this] val CLASS_TYPE: Int = _;
    <stable> <accessor> def CLASS_TYPE(): Int = hello.this.CLASS_TYPE;
    final <synthetic> def delayedEndpoint$hello$1: Unit = {
      hello.this.baseSize = 256;
      hello.this.MIN_DATA_PAGE_SIZE = scala.math.`package`.max(hello.this.baseSize(), 1024);
      hello.this.MAX_DATA_PAGE_SIZE = hello.this.MIN_DATA_PAGE_SIZE().*(scala.math.`package`.pow(2.0, hello.this.CLASS_TYPE().-(1).toDouble()).toInt());
      hello.this.CLASS_TYPE = 2;
      scala.this.Predef.println(scala.Int.box(hello.this.MAX_DATA_PAGE_SIZE()));
      ()
    };
    def <init>(): hello.type = {
      hello.super.<init>();
      scala.App$class./*App$class*/$init$(hello.this);
      hello.this.delayedInit(new hello$delayedInit$body(hello.this));
      ()
    }
  };
  final <synthetic> class hello$delayedInit$body extends runtime.AbstractFunction0 {
    <paramaccessor> private[this] val $outer: hello.type = _;
    final def apply(): Object = {
      hello$delayedInit$body.this.$outer.delayedEndpoint$hello$1();
      scala.runtime.BoxedUnit.UNIT
    };
    def <init>($outer: hello.type): hello$delayedInit$body = {
      if ($outer.eq(null))
        throw null
      else
        hello$delayedInit$body.this.$outer = $outer;
      hello$delayedInit$body.super.<init>();
      ()
    }
  }
}

one warning found
```

This will not cause a compilation error but definitely **undefined behaviour**.

If you load the class into the REPL and run it twice it gives the right answer as `CLASS_TYPE` has been initalised properly.

```
scala> :load -v hello.scala
Loading hello.scala...

scala> object hello extends App{
     |     val baseSize = 256
     |     val MIN_DATA_PAGE_SIZE = math.max(baseSize, 1024)
     |     val MAX_DATA_PAGE_SIZE =  MIN_DATA_PAGE_SIZE * scala.math.pow(2, CLASS_TYPE-1).toInt
     |     val CLASS_TYPE: Int = 2
     | 
     |     println(MAX_DATA_PAGE_SIZE)
     | }
<console>:10: warning: Reference to uninitialized value CLASS_TYPE
           val MAX_DATA_PAGE_SIZE =  MIN_DATA_PAGE_SIZE * scala.math.pow(2, CLASS_TYPE-1).toInt
                                                                            ^
defined object hello

scala> hello.main(Array())
0

scala> hello.main(Array())
2048
```

This is to do with the way objects extending App trait are compiled.

If you wrote a normal application like this:

```
object hello {

def main(args:Array[String]) {
    val baseSize = 256
    val MIN_DATA_PAGE_SIZE = math.max(baseSize, 1024)
    val MAX_DATA_PAGE_SIZE =  MIN_DATA_PAGE_SIZE * scala.math.pow(2, CLASS_TYPE-1).toInt
    val CLASS_TYPE: Int = 2

    println(MAX_DATA_PAGE_SIZE)
  }
}
```

and try and compile it you get the following error:

```
~$ scalac hello.scala
hello.scala:6: error: forward reference extends over definition of value MAX_DATA_PAGE_SIZE
val MAX_DATA_PAGE_SIZE =  MIN_DATA_PAGE_SIZE * scala.math.pow(2, CLASS_TYPE-1).toInt
                                                                         ^
one error found
```

Comment: Thanks very much! so the sequence of variable declaration have a  influence on the code, I  always think that code in scala is just like c++, as long as you declare a field in one class, not matter you put it in the beginning,  or in the end.

Comment: That's not exactly true, it's because you are using the App trait, I've updated my answer with a normal example

Answer (score 1):

Compiler gave your a warning on compilation, like

```
[warn] Reference to uninitialized value CLASS_TYPE
[warn]   val MAX_DATA_PAGE_SIZE =  MIN_DATA_PAGE_SIZE * scala.math.pow(2, CLASS_TYPE-1).toInt
[warn]                                                                    ^
[warn] one warning found
```

best way to fix this is to use more strict compiler options. Add to your build.sbt

```
scalacOptions ++= Seq(
"-unchecked",
"-deprecation",
"-feature",
"-Xfatal-warnings",
"-language:postfixOps",
"-Ywarn-unused-import"
)
```

Also note, that according [scala style](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html) you should note your constants like

```
MaxDataPageSize
ClassType
```

and so on.